# What is the side effect when leaving the IP address of site binding unassigned?

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, ip-address, bindings

[image]

What is the side effect when leaving the IP address of site binding unassigned?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What this does it create a binding on the address 0.0.0.0 (and ipv6's equivilent, ::); it will accept connections on that port via any address that the system has, including the localhost address at 127.0.0.1, as well as any and all configured IP addresses.

The reason that this is configurable is if you are looking to have a different web site accepting connections on several different configured IP addresses on the same server.  (however, this approach is not necessary for hosting multiple sites; utilizing [host headers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753195(WS.10).aspx) with 1 IP address and leaving the IP set to "All Unassigned" is generally preferable)

Comment: How to make a single server have many ip addresses?

Comment: To add additional IP address on the device, you'll go into the TCP/IPv4 settings for the network card.  (Your primary address must be statically configured for this to work; no DHCP)  Under advanced, in the IP addresses section there is a section for adding additional addresses.

Comment: Why is using one IP address with host headers preferable?